# How can I link with a directory which might not exist while running?

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries

I'm writing a library for Linux which has some functionality which relies on the a shared library libfoo.so.

I'm trying to case where libfoo.so doesn't exist into consideration. I have a well defined behavior for such a case, but I don't know how to properly implement it, linkage wise.

Currently, my library is shipped compiled against libfoo.so, when a client tries to compile it's code against it on an environment which doesn't include libfoo.so he gets linkage errors.

My question is, how can I build my library in such a way that it would compile even if libfoo.so doesn't exist, but behave differently. The only solution I was able to come up with myself is to branch from it a version which doesn't support foo, but there must be a better way...

Thanks in advance

A follow up due to the given answer:
It seems that not linking against libfoo but rather dynamically loading it with dlopen solves the problem, but it requires me to manually export all the symbols, and is limited in scope... Is there any "less painful" to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different problems that kind of fit the description, depending on whether the presence of the library is to be detected at compile time or at runtime.

At compile time you will have to use some tool to detect whether the library is present and modify the build scripts to pass that information down to the code (think defines).

At runtime, you can avoid linking against the library, and rather dynamically load it. The code should handle failures to locate/load the library and fall back to the alternative version.

Comment: I don't think prep macros will be useful in the code, as the library ships precompiled, and it should support both cases...

Comment: Well, I've investigated loading the library dynamically, which seems to solve the problem... but at the cost of having to manually export all the symbols I need to use (at least when using dlopen).
Do you know of a ... friendlier way to do that?

Comment: AFAIK gcc exports all symbols by default, are you using the `-fvisibility=hidden` command line flag? Depending on what the library is, it might be worth to just write a simple wrapper and export that wrapper. That will also have the advantage of allowing for a simple replacement in the event of the library not being present (by having a similar *wrapper* that will implement a different version of the functionality)